# lodash, check if collection contains object with property of value

Tags: lodash

this filters replacement_codes by a collection of items with a property of code that is in replacement_codes. The code works as expected but is not very readable.

```
return this.replacement_codes.filter((code) => {
    let length = this.items.length;
    for (let index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        if (this.items[index].code === code) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get lodash to do this for me.

The following code works. Now i can't figure out how to use lodash to get a boolean result for checking if a collection contains a property with a given value.

```
return _.filter(this.replacement_codes, (code) => {
    let length = this.replacements.length;
    for (let index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        if (this.replacements[index].code === code) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});
```

Boiling it down a step further:

```
let items = [
    {
        code: 'a',
        value: 'something1'
    },
    {
        code: 'b',
        value: 'something2'
    },
    {
        code: 'c',
        value: 'something3'
    },
    {
        code: 'd',
        value: 'something4'
    },
];

let array_to_filter = ['a', 'd', 'z', 'x'];
```

i want the filtered array to be ['z', 'x'];

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve this using _.differenceWith

```
let items = [
    {
        code: 'a',
        value: 'something1'
    },
    {
        code: 'b',
        value: 'something2'
    },
    {
        code: 'c',
        value: 'something3'
    },
    {
        code: 'd',
        value: 'something4'
    },
  ];

  let array_to_filter = ['a', 'd', 'z', 'x'];

  let r = _.differenceWith(array_to_filter, items, (f, i) => f == i.code );

  console.log(r)
```